# How to display singular_name of custom taxonomy?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm displaying list of term from each taxonomy assigned to custom post:

```
<?php $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post );
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, '<span class="e-article__category__item"><strong>' . SINGULAR_NAME . ': </strong>  ', ", ", '</span>' );
} ?>
```

but here, in SINGULAR_NAME I would like to display the singular_name of custom taxonomy.

I was trying this:

```
<?php $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post );
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

$term_name = $taxonomy->labels->singular_name;

the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, '<span class="e-article__category__item"><strong>' . $term_name . ': </strong>  ', ", ", '</span>' );
} ?>
```

What I want to do is show all terms, separately for each taxonomy, but before each list I want to display taxonomy name (singular_name).

How to do that correctly?

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Piotr, what do you mean by "singular_name of CPT"? What exactly do you want to print? Could you update your question and add the effect you want to achieve?

Comment: Cześć, Krzysztof:) I mean singular_name of custom taxonomy, my mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware, your question has been answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/239097/89412).

You're getting the singular_name correctly, all you need to do is echo it.

```
<?php $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post );
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {

$term_name = $taxonomy->labels->singular_name;

echo $term_name;

the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy, '<span class="e-article__category__item"><strong>' . $term_name . ': </strong>  ', ", ", '</span>' );
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally get this done:

```
<?php $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post, 'objects' );
foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
$tax_name = $taxonomy->labels->singular_name;
the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy->name, '<span class="e-article__category__item"><strong>' . $tax_name . ': </strong>  ', ", ", '</span>' );
} ?>
```

thanks :)